# Testing functions containing async (without setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, testing, mocha.js

I want to test `myFunction()`, which is expected to turn `var appState` from `"old state"` to `"new state"`. However, `myFunction()` invokes n functions `fetcher()` which contain the async function `fetch` - similar to the psudocode below.

```
// Application code

myFunction() = function {
    for (var i = 0, len = myarray.length; i < len; i++) {
          fetcher()
     }
}

fetcher = function(){
    fetch(url) // Is asynchronous
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        if(data == 'abc'){ appState = "new state" }
    }
}

// Test

myFunction()

setTimeout(() => {  
    assert.equal(appState, "New State")
}, 10);
```

This timeout works fine and the test passes, but it feels like a code smell. Is there a more correct way to wait for the async functions generated by `myFunction()` to complete before testing the new state?

Comment: Well there is nothing you can attach to to know the call is complete. And there is no async/await. You would have to change the code to use Promise.all to know when all the calls are done. So the answer is you have to change your code.

Comment: Useful - cheers.

Answer (score 2):

async / await is the way to go!

```js
// Application code

myFunction() = async function {
    for (var i = 0, len = myarray.length; i < len; i++) {
          await fetcher()
     }
}

fetcher = async function(){
    const respons = await fetch(url) // Is asynchronous
    const data = await response.json())
    if(data == 'abc'){ appState = "new state" }
}

// Your test now should look like this:

async function test() {
    await myFunc()
    assert.equal(appState, "New State")
}

test()
```

async / await is awesome!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise you could put async on a fundamentally not-asynchronous function.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to utilize promises or use Async/Await

```js
const fakeFetch = (url) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({
      json: () => new Promise((resolveJSON) => resolveJSON({
        myKey: url === 3 ? 'abc' : 'foo'
      })),
    });
  }, Math.ceil(1000 * Math.random()));
});

let appState = 'x';
const myarray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];


const myFunction = function() {
  var myPromises = [];
  for (var i = 0, len = myarray.length; i < len; i++) {
    myPromises.push(fetcher(myarray[i]))
  }
  return Promise.all(myPromises);
  // return Promise.allSettled(myPromises);
}

// const myFunction = function() {
//   return Promise.allSettled(myarray.map(x => fetcher(x)));
// }


const fetcher = function(url) {
  return fakeFetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.myKey == 'abc') {
        appState = "new state"
      }
    });
}


myFunction().then( function () {
  console.assert(appState === "New State", "appState", appState);
});
```

```js
const fakeFetch = (url) => new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve({
      json: () => new Promise((resolveJSON) => resolveJSON({
        myKey: url === 3 ? 'abc' : 'foo'
      })),
    });
  }, Math.ceil(1000 * Math.random()));
});

let appState = 'x';
const myarray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];


const myFunction = async function() {
  for (var i = 0, len = myarray.length; i < len; i++) {
    await fetcher(myarray[i])
  }
}

const fetcher = async (url) => {
  const response = await fakeFetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  if (data.myKey == 'abc') {
    appState = "new state"
  }
}

const test = async () => {
  await myFunction();
  console.assert(appState === "New State", "appState", appState);
};

test();
```